# SyntaxError: invalid syntax while building z3

Tags: z3

I downloaded z3 source codes from the master branch and tried to build it, which resulted in the following error:

```
c:\Program Files\z3>python --version
Python 3.3.2

c:\Program Files\z3>python scripts\mk_make.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts\mk_make.py", line 9, in <module>
    from mk_util import *
  File "c:\Program Files\z3\scripts\mk_util.py", line 81
    print "dos2unix '%s'" % fname
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The master branch only works with Python 2.7.x.
The unstable (working-in-progress) branch should work with Python 3.x.
[Here are instructions](https://z3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Building%20the%20unstable%20%28working-in-progress%29%20branch&referringTitle=Documentation) to compile the working-in-progress branch.